# How to calculate the average and max of a beta distribution?

Tags: distributions, beta-distribution

I have a beta distribution where the values of alpha and beta are given. And the value of `x` varies from 0 to 1. I need to calculate the average and mode of this distribution.

- How can I calculate the average? (I could not get a formula for with a simple google search. )
- How should I calculate the mode?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're asking. Perhaps see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) on the beta distribution
if neither of my guesses below is helpful.

If you know that the distribution is $\mathsf{Beta}(\alpha, \beta),$ then the max is $1,$ as for all beta distributions, and the mean is
$\mu = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}.$

Density function $f(x) = 12x(1-x)^2,$ for $0\le x\le 1,$ of $\mathsf{Beta}(2,3)$ with mean $\mu = 2/5 = 0.4$ is shown below.

```
curve(dbeta(x, 2, 3), 0, 1, lwd=2, ylab="PDF", main="Density of BETA(2,3)")
 abline(h=0, col="green2");  abline(v=0, col="green2")
 abline(v=0.4, col="red")
```

[image]

If you have a very large sample `x` from a beta distribution with unknown
parameters, you could use `summary(x)` to get good estimates.

For example:

```
set.seed(2020)
x = rbeta(10^6, 2, 3)
summary(x)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
0.0001371 0.2430357 0.3855599 0.3998891 0.5433648 0.9915185
```

The same thing would work for a large sample from any distribution
that has a mean and a finite maximum.

**Addendum** per Comment on mode.

It is a little more difficult to estimate the mode of a continuous distribution from
a sample. One way is to make a histogram and try to guess the mode from the position of the 'tallest' bar in the histogram. This doesn't always work well
because a different histogram of the data with different bins may give a very
different answer.

Another method is to use a density estimator, illustrated in R below. For reference, here is a histogram of the large sample 'x' above,
along with the density estimator of the sample `x`. In R, the procedure 'density' fits a kernel density estimator (KDE) to the data (without reference to the histogram).

```
hist(x, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2")
 lines(density(x), col="brown", lwd=2)
```

[image]

The 'density' is consists of 512 x-values and 512 y-values used to plot the brown curve above. The mode of the population is estimated by finding the
density x-value corresponding to the highest y-value, as follows:

```
dx = density(x)$x;  dy = density(x)$y
dx[dy==max(dy)]
[1] 0.328921
```

The mode of $\mathsf{Beta}(2,3)$ is
$\delta = \frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha+\beta -2} = 1/3,$ so our estimate
$0.3289$ from the large sample `x` is quite good.

Comment: When alpha = 2 and Beta = 5, mean is `0.2857`. Does that mean that I can just substitute x as `0.2857` in my equation and get the mean value?

Comment: Also, how can I calculate the max value?

Comment: Seems you have the right idea for the mean. See link. All beta distributions have support $[0,1],$ so the max of a beta population is $1.$

Comment: is the max always at 1? There are beta distributions that peak at 0,5. Given an alpha and beta and the range of x (which is 0 to 1), is there a formula to find out the  max? I could not find out a equation for max in the link?

Comment: Yes. Maximum of a beta population is always 1. Maximum of a large enough sample will be nearly 1. Look at density functions in the link. I will post a figure for BETA(2, 3).

Comment: Maybe you're confusing 'max' with 'mode'. The mode of a density function is the value of $x$ at which the density function reaches a maximum (if such an $x$ exists). For $\mathsf{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$ with $\alpha, \beta > 1,$ link says mode is at $x=\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha+\beta-2}.$ [Simple differentiation exercise.]